# Random # of results returned by Twitter search API

Tags: node.js, twitter

Doing a Twitter API query such as:

```
https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?q=%23freebandnames&count=100
```

returns, most of the time, less results than I specify in count.

If I specify 100, I might get 87, 63, rarely 100.

If I specify 10, I might get 7, 0, and so on.

Clearly this is not a limit on the # of available results.

Any idea why this is? I am using the node `twitter` module but I can see from using nock recorder that twitter indeed returns this seemingly random # of results.

Comment: For what it's worth: I see the same behaviour (less than count), and it appears it's by design. e.g. count=100 will return 90-something tweets, count=50 will return 42, etc. Note that the API seems to be extremely dysfunctional and the "next_results" URL will often by empty even if more tweets do exist.

Comment: dysfunctional is the word here :) I  get 0 results many times in a row if I choose 10 as my count.

Comment: Yes. If you want to paginate results, it's critical you follow the [Working with Timelines](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/timelines/overview) guide: that is, track the lowest tweet.ID you see, and use (that - 1) as the `max_id` parameter (cursor). You should also track the `maxId` returned in the `search_metadata` if you want to avoid searching for duplicates (i.e. you try the same search 5 minutes later).

Comment: @cyberwombat I'm curious what searches yield 0 for you. The only time I have seen this is when there were no valid tweets less than a week old.

Comment: So I was searching for `#bitcoin` to do a sentiment analysis. At some point in my testing I used a limit of 10 and tried to fulfill 100 records (I know I can request 100 off the bat) and wondered why I was suddenly blocked for too many request. Rerunning with logs I could see that many requests yielded less than 10 and many of them zero. So while I can eventually get 100 (notwithstanding api limit) it takes way more than 100/limit.  I may be messing up the paging which is a possibility and I will continue looking into that though evidently I am not the only one getting these odd counts.

Answer (score 2):

`count` is an upper limit. However, it is not the only limiting factor. `search/tweets` will not return tweets older than about week. This could be the reason why you are sometimes getting fewer tweets than you specify with `count`.

Using your example, searching for "#freebandnames", I get no results. Searching for the same hashtag on twitter.com I see the last time this hashtag was tweeted was on Dec 6. That is too old to show up in a `search/tweets` request.

EDIT
If you are missing tweets that are less than a week old, this is very possible only because we don't really know what Twitter is doing behind the scenes. In the docs you will see that, unlike  "Premium",  this "Standard" endpoint is "Incomplete" - [doc](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/search/overview). Also, there is a parameter `result_type` - [doc](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/search/api-reference/get-search-tweets) - which you can set to `popular` or `recent`. (Default is `mixed`.) You will notice that `popular` more often returns the number specified by `count`. Twitter must apply an algorithm to return better quality tweets that match your filter. In doing so it must remove poor quality tweets but only after first gathering the `count` number of tweets.

Comment: I can understand that there are less total tweets but that is not issue. Use anther tag - I just gabbed that one from Twitter's docs. I tried #bitcoin for ex. If I ask for 10 I get anywhere between 0 and 10. I fi ask for a 100 ( get anywhere between 0 and 100 - so its not a total tweet limit. It means I hit my api rate trying to get 1000 tweets because I end up making hundreds of call rather than the expected 10 (at a 100 max limit)

Comment: See my edit. If you need a specific number of tweets you may need to make additional requests to fulfill the order.

Comment: Thanks but again not related. I am of course paging my requests. I am not trying to get multiple pages here - I am trying to understand why the api is ,as elithrar called it, "dysfunctional". result_type make no diff. It just appears to return a random result between 0 and limit with each call.

Comment: You shoud post your question on Twitter's forum at https://twittercommunity.com/. I think what I said does relate. Twitter removes some tweets that it deems irrelevant. So, if you ask for 100, and 3 are irrelevant (such as spam), you will get 97 tweets.